# How to return a vector when connecting R with Tableau?

Tags: r, tableau-api, calculated-field, rserve

I'm trying to return a vector through a Tableau calculated field. According to link below, Tableau can either receive a single value or a vector using connections to R through a calculated field.

http://community.tableau.com/docs/DOC-5313

see:

> "...If the R code returns a matrix of values, Tableau won’t know what to do, we have to return a single value or a vector,..."

This is what I have in my calculated field, where Parameter 1 and Parameter 2 are just arbitrary values (just for demonstration purposes):

```
SCRIPT_REAL ('testvector <- c(.arg1, .arg2); testvector',min([Parameter 1]), min([Parameter 2]))
```

I was expected a single vector to be returned, but I'm getting the following error message:

```
## Error: Unexpected number of results returned by SCRIPT function.  Function expected 1 values; 2 values were returned.
```

Answer (score 2):

You are not actually returning a value; just assigning 3 vectors in `Rserve` environment. You need to return `testvector` after the assignment:

```
SCRIPT_REAL('column1 <- c(.arg1, .arg2); 
            column2 <- c(.arg3, .arg4); 
            testvector <- c(column1,column2);
            testvector', 
            min([Parameter 1]), min([Parameter 2]),min([Parameter 3]), min([Parameter 4]))
```

Comment: I'm confused.  Why were there 3 vectors being created?  It seems like there should only be one- `testvector <- c(column1, column2)`.  Also, I added a single line `testvector` to my script but it didn't solve the problem. I'm still getting the same error message.

Comment: I think you edited the title of my original posting- unexpected number of results returned by script function

Comment: You need to explicitly specify which vector to return to Tableau. Without specifying `... ;testvector`, `Rserve` doesn't know which of the 3 vectors (i.e: `column1`, `column2` or `testvector`) to return.

Comment: in my first comment I mentioned "Also, I added a single line testvector to my script but it didn't solve the problem. I'm still getting the same error message".  I think it has something to do with the view I'm trying to put it on.  For example, this site: [link](http://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/pro/online/mac/en-us/r_connection_troubleshoot.html)  says this: _The R script result must be either a scalar or vector of length one that is replicated for all rows, or a vector of length equal to the number of rows in the Tableau result table._

Comment: Try it on a sheet with no other pills on the shelves

Comment: @RyanChase Try to reduce your example with only one argument. Something like `'testvector <- .arg1; testvector, MIN([Parameter 1])'`

Comment: If I simplify it to what you're suggesting it will no longer be a  vector.  It would be a single value.

Comment: ...I've simplified the example nonetheless.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84485/discussion-between-steven-beaupre-and-ryan-chase).

Answer (score 0):

If the table in which you're using this calculated field has 1 row and Parameter1 value is 9 and Parameter2 values is 5, with code example you posted, you are creating a vector that looks like (9,5) which has 2 rows.

So the table 1 row but calculated field returns 2 rows. Hence the error message

"Function expected 1 values; 2 values were returned."

If you'd like to get a vector back, you will need to pass a vector. You can take a look at the k-means clustering example on [R integration introductory blog post](http://www.tableau.com/about/blog/2013/10/tableau-81-and-r-25327) which passes several vectors that comprise the Iris dataset and gets a vector back with cluster assignments.